# Fill a listbox with an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, listbox

I am afraid I have a relatively specific issue. I try to fill a `ListBox` with a dynamic array. The code so far seems to work fine (according to F8) and the array should be filled.

Just for completion sake: A `For` loop goes through every cell of a column and along with many `if` statements checks if the current cell has a specific Letter (for example "A") inside. If so, add one Letter (For example "A") to the array.

There are 97 rows in that column and around 50 should match the if statements.

Then the easy answer would be:
`Tabelle.Listbox.List = Array`

But it doesn't work. Right now, the `ListBox` shows only 9 empty rows.
Just to be sure, I also enter 1 `if` statement here (there are more but this shouldn't matter, I guess ^^).

I know the code overall could be improved but lets fix the error first :D

```
Dim ArrNutzer As Variant
Dim VarNutzerSpalte As Integer
Dim VarNutzerZeilen As Integer
Dim VarAktuellerNutzer As String

Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim l As Integer

For i = 1 To VarAnzahlSpalten
    VarAktuellerWert = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value
        If VarAktuellerWert Like "Nutzer" Then
            VarNutzerSpalte = i
        End If
Next i

k = 0
VarNutzerZeilen = Worksheets("Filter").Cells(Rows.Count, VarNutzerSpalte).End(xlUp).Row 

ReDim ArrNutzer(k) As String 

For j = 2 To VarNutzerZeilen

    VarAktuellerNutzer = Worksheets("Filter").Cells(j, VarNutzerSpalte).Value 

    If VarAktuellerNutzer Like "*A*" Then
            ArrNutzer(k) = "A"
            k = k + 1
            ReDim ArrNutzer(k) As String
    End If
Next j

FilterAuswahl.ListBoxPID.List = ArrNutzer
FilterAuswahl.Show
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
ReDim ArrNutzer(k) As String
```

is emptying the array. You need to use:

```
ReDim Preserve ArrNutzer(k) As String
```

to maintain the content, and you should use it before incrementing k or you'll end up with a blank row.

Comment: Thank you a lot it worked ^^
.. but kinda stupid that the default is to empty the array.. i kinda get why but still...